# Spotify Web API - limit and offset aren't recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify, offset

I am trying to use spotify-web-api-node to get all tracks of a playlist. The default limit of tracks is 100, so I want to retrieve them in chunks. For this I need the offset setting when making the API call. But it seems that neither offset or limit actuall work.

Call:

```
let limit = 100
let offset = 100

let ret_array = []
let playlistResponse

playlistResponse = await spotifyApi.getPlaylistTracks(playlistId, {
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset,
})

console.log(playlistResponse)
```

When loging the response the both are not recognized:

body.
tracks: {

```
  limit: 100,
  next: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/7q9zstf4jYXiHWGrkutLPQ/tracks?offset=100&limit=100',
  offset: 0,
  previous: null,
  href: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/7q9zstf4jYXiHWGrkutLPQ/tracks?offset=0&limit=100',
  total: 160,
  items: [Array]
}
```

What could cause the problem here?
What about the "next" url? Can I make use of that in some way?

Thanks